# Define a macro based on parameter

Tags: macros

I am trying to create a macro that creates two macros. The first sets a default value and the second creates a macro to redefine the first. I am trying to generalize a common pattern I am using quite a bit.

```
\newcommand{\mkMac}[1]{%
\newcommand{\the#1}{The macro ##1}
\newcommand{\#1}[1]{\renewcommand{\the#1}{##1}}
}
```

Usage:

```
\mkMac{affilation}
\affilation{University}
Welcome to \theaffilation
```

Comment: This has been asked before. Can you give some more context?

Comment: I added context. I searched for a similar question, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: This may be relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109615/best-practice-for-creating-user-defined-command-names

Comment: \the syntax is used for LaTeX counter and lengths so you would better off with a different prefix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand` you have to use `\csname...\endcsname`, with some `\expandafter` to build the control sequence before `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand` comes into action:

```
\newcommand{\mkMac}[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname the#1\endcsname{%
    Call the macro \texttt{\expandafter\string\csname #1\endcsname}!%
  }%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname[1]{%
    \expandafter\renewcommand\csname the#1\endcsname{##1}%
  }%
}

\mkMac{affiliation}
\show\theaffiliation
\show\affiliation
\affiliation{University}
\show\theaffiliation

\stop
```

This is the output on the terminal when running the example (`\stop` is just to end the run):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mkmak.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
> \theaffiliation=\long macro:
->Call the macro \texttt {\expandafter \string \csname affiliation\endcsname }!.
l.11 \show\theaffiliation

?
> \affiliation=\long macro:
#1->\expandafter \renewcommand \csname theaffiliation\endcsname {#1}.
l.12 \show\affiliation

?
> \theaffiliation=\long macro:
->University.
l.14 \show\theaffiliation

?
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on mkmak.log.
```

So `\mkMak{affiliation}` defines a temporary value for `\theaffiliation` and the macro `\affiliation`; the call `\affiliation{University}` redefines `\theaffiliation` to `University`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)’ `\csdef` but in this case LaTeX won’t test if a macro is defined already.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\mkMac}[1]{%
  \csdef{the#1}{The macro ##1}
  \csdef{#1}##1{\csdef{the#1}{##1}}
}
```

Note that with `\csdef` the braces around the macro name are mandatory and the leading backslash must be omitted.

Comment: I think that \csdef{#1}##1{\csdef{#1}{##1}} should be \csdef{#1}##1{\csdef{the#1}{##1}}

Comment: @Raisdead: You’re right. Didn’t test is since you din’t provide a MWE ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you don’t want to think about expansion and want to use the functions of `\newcommand`, you can use the macros `\csnewcommand` and `\recsnewcommand` defined as

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\csnewcommand{\@star@or@long\csnew@command}
\newcommand*\csnew@command[1]{\expandafter\new@command\csname#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*\recsnewcommand{\@star@or@long\recsnew@command}
\newcommand*\recsnew@command[1]{\expandafter\renew@command\csname#1\endcsname}
\makeatletter
```

This way you can use both the starred and un-starred version without `\expandafter`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\csnewcommand{\@star@or@long\csnew@command}
\newcommand*\csnew@command[1]{\expandafter\new@command\csname#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*\recsnewcommand{\@star@or@long\recsnew@command}
\newcommand*\recsnew@command[1]{\expandafter\renew@command\csname#1\endcsname}
\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\mkMac}[1]{%
  \csnewcommand*{the#1}{The macro #1}%
  \csnewcommand*{#1}[1]{\recsnewcommand*{the#1}{##1}}}
  
\begin{document}
\mkMac{affilation}
Welcome to ``\theaffilation''.

\affilation{University}
Welcome to ``\theaffilation''.
\end{document}
```

### Output

> Welcome to “The macro affilation”.
>
> Welcome to “University”.

Answer (score 1):

The two-line solution which uses only TeX primitives follows:

```
\def\sdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname}
\def\mkMac#1{\sdef{the#1}{The macro #1}\sdef{#1}##1{\sdef{the#1}{##1}}}

\mkMac{affilation}
\affilation{University}
Welcome to \theaffilation
```

Comment: Without any control whatsoever about the macro already having a definition.

Comment: We are using TeX and this is normal behavior of TeX. The question doesn't include explicitly the task about this more intelligence. But if somebody needs this, then my macro would have three lines no two lines. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX defines a short interface similar to that provided by [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) in the form of `\@namedef` (from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)):

```
\def\@namedef#1{\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname}
```

Here is a minimal example showing the usage:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mkMac}[1]{%
  \@namedef{the#1}{The macro #1}%
  \@namedef{#1}##1{\@namedef{the#1}{##1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mkMac{affilation}
Welcome to ``\theaffilation''.

\affilation{University}
Welcome to ``\theaffilation''.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Without any control whatsoever about the macro already having a definition. This is essentially the same answer as Tobi's.