# Defining 3*(2^4) complex macro at once

Tags: math-mode, macros, etoolbox, xparse

An Automata can be

- 1- or 2- ways,
- With Several Heads or a Single head
- Deterministic or Non-deterministic
- With a stack or not

That makes 2^4 = 16 possibilities.
However, for each combination, I'd like to define several macros:

1. An abbreviation (e.g. 2MDFA+S for a "2-ways multi-head deterministic finite automata with stack")
2. An extended version (e.g. to fully write "2-ways multi-head deterministic finite automata with stack")
3. An abbreviation in a different font-face (e.g. **2MDFA+S**)
4. In the case of a multi-headed automata, the posibility to display the number of head in parenthesis (e.g 2MDFA+S(3) for a "2-ways 3-heads deterministic finite automata with stack")

I would like not to write at each time what I want, but to massively use macro, to prevent typographic errors and misspellings. And, of course, to be able to change easily the displaying if I want to.

---

I know [that I can define shorthands quickly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30349/defining-multiple-shorthands-quickly), [use `\csname...\endcsname`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131391/define-a-macro-based-on-parameter?rq=1) or [define macros that define macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65780/macro-defining-macro) but that still leave me 16 combinations to define.

I know [that I can test for equality of a parameter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61598/new-command-with-cases-conditionals-if-thens) thanks to the `xstring` package, but that force me to duplicate several `if` tests.
That would (I guess) to have macros like \fa{1}{M}{D}{S}, but I don't mind.

There is the additional difficulty that I cannot just "print the name of the macro", since I want "\O..." (for "one-way") to be printed with the number "1...".

---

Some kind of (lousy) attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}

% Underline for the example, but that could be a different font.
\newcommand{\bold}[1]{\underline{#1}}

% This part allows to have as an optional argument the number of heads.
% This is item 4 in the question.
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\abbrFA}{m g}{%
    \text{#1}
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}% then
                    {}% else
                    {(#2)}% fi
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\OMDFAS}{g}{%
    \def\notation{$1$MDFA+S}
            \IfNoValueTF{#1}% then
                {\abbrFA{\notation}}% else
                {\abbrFA{\notation}{#1}}% fi
}

\newcommand{\longOMDFAS}{$1$-way Multi-Head Finite Automata with Stack} 
% How to get this automatically for every combination?

\begin{document}
\(\OMDFAS\)

\(\OMDFAS{k}\)

\longOMDFAS

\(\bold{\OMDFAS}\)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course, I do not want to have a solution, but just some advices on how you would proceed.

Comment: I don't know anything about “automata”, but 48 macros could be reduced to 48 —short— lines (with some “generator”), which I think is not too much. Of course, you may be able to use loops (`\loop`, or a more usual `\foreach`). But still: 48 lines is not that much. That said, I repeat, I don't know anything about what you want, I was just doing numbers :)

Comment: After reading: would something like `\automata{1MDF+S}` be acceptable?

Comment: @Manuel Of course.

Comment: @Clément How many heads are allowed? Does one digit suffice?

Comment: Well, then `\automata{1MDF+S}` the extended one, `\automata*{…}` the short version, `\automata+{…}` the “different font”. That's easy with `xparse`. Now to process the inside of the argument, some `\tl_…` functions from `expl3` would come in handy. However I think it would be easier if you only use 1 token for each variety, that is, instead of `+S` just `+`, and then let the macro see if it sees a `+` or no. I will think about it later, right now I can't compile :)

Comment: @egreg : it can be any figure or a variable (i.e. `k`, `k+1`, etc).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should be what you want. The mandatory argument to `\fa` should be a four character string:

- First byte:  1 or 2 (one way or two way)
- Second byte: S or M (single or multi head)
- Third byte:  D or N (deterministic or non deterministic)
- Fourth byte: + or - (with or without stack)

The optional argument is the number of heads, while the macro `\fa` can be followed by `*` for printing the abbreviation in boldface or by `+` for the long version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fa}{ s t+ m o }
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#4}
   {% there is no trailing optional argument, set the boolean to false
    \bool_set_false:N \l_clement_show_heads_bool
   }
   {% there is a trailing optional argument, set the boolean to false
    \bool_set_true:N \l_clement_show_heads_bool
    % and store the argument for later usage
    \tl_set:Nn \l_clement_heads_tl { $#4$ }
   }
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}
   {% the `+` modifier has been given, call the long version
    \clement_fa_long:n { #3 }
   }
   {% no + modifier
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
     {% the `*` modifier has been given, call the short version in \textbf
      \textbf{\clement_fa_short:n { #3 }}
     }
     {% no `*` modifier, just call the short version
      \clement_fa_short:n { #3 }
     }
   }
 }

% First byte:  1 or 2 (one way or two way)
% Second byte: S or M (single or multi head)
% Third byte:  D or N (deterministic or non deterministic)
% Fourth byte: + or - (with or without stack)

\bool_new:N \l_clement_show_heads_bool
\tl_new:N \l_clement_heads_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \clement_fa_short:n #1
 {% separate the four characters
  \clement_fa_short_aux:NNNN #1
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \clement_fa_short_aux:NNNN #1 #2 #3 #4
 {% just use #1, #2 and #3 and add FA
  #1#2#3FA
  \str_case:nn { #4 }
   {% check if the fourth character is - or +
    {-}{}% -: do nothing
    {+}{+S}% +: add +S
   }
  % if the boolean is true, add the number of heads in parentheses
  \bool_if:NT \l_clement_show_heads_bool { (\l_clement_heads_tl) }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \clement_fa_long:n #1
 {% separate the four characters
  \clement_fa_long_aux:NNNN #1
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \clement_fa_long_aux:NNNN #1 #2 #3 #4
 {% add 1-way or 2-way and a space
  #1-way~%
  \bool_if:NTF \l_clement_show_heads_bool
   {% if the boolean is true, add the number of heads
    \l_clement_heads_tl
   }
   {% else add S if single-head, M if multi-head
    \str_case:nn { #2 }
     {
      {S}{single}
      {M}{multi}
     }
   }
  -head~% add -head and a space
  \str_case:nn { #3 }
   {% add `non` and a space if nondeterministic
    {N}{non~}
    {D}{}
   }
  deterministic~finite~automaton~% the words
  \str_case:nn { #4 }
   {% add `with` or `without`
    {+}{with~}
    {-}{without~}
   }
  stack% add `stack`
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\fa{2MD+} --- \fa+{2MD+}

\fa{2MD-}[3] --- \fa+{2MD-}[3]

\fa*{2MN+}[k+1] --- \fa+{2MN-}[k+1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the word is *automaton* (automata is plural) and there should be no “s” in the prefixes (*two way*, not *two ways*; 3-head, not 3-heads), according to English grammar.

---

A variation that prints the number of heads parenthesized in the long form, when it's not an explicit number and it contains more than a symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fa}{ s t+ m o }
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#4}
   {% there is no trailing optional argument, set the boolean to false
    \bool_set_false:N \l_clement_show_heads_bool
   }
   {% there is a trailing optional argument, set the boolean to false
    \bool_set_true:N \l_clement_show_heads_bool
    % and store the argument for later usage
    \tl_set:Nn \l_clement_heads_tl { #4 }
   }
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}
   {% the `+` modifier has been given, call the long version
    \clement_fa_long:n { #3 }
   }
   {% no + modifier
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
     {% the `*` modifier has been given, call the short version in \textbf
      \textbf{\clement_fa_short:n { #3 }}
     }
     {% no `*` modifier, just call the short version
      \clement_fa_short:n { #3 }
     }
   }
 }

% First byte:  1 or 2 (one way or two way)
% Second byte: S or M (single or multi head)
% Third byte:  D or N (deterministic or non deterministic)
% Fourth byte: + or - (with or without stack)

\bool_new:N \l_clement_show_heads_bool
\tl_new:N \l_clement_heads_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \clement_fa_short:n #1
 {% separate the four characters
  \clement_fa_short_aux:NNNN #1
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \clement_fa_short_aux:NNNN #1 #2 #3 #4
 {% just use #1, #2 and #3 and add FA
  #1#2#3FA
  \str_case:nn { #4 }
   {% check if the fourth character is - or +
    {-}{}% -: do nothing
    {+}{+S}% +: add +S
   }
  % if the boolean is true, add the number of heads in parentheses
  \bool_if:NT \l_clement_show_heads_bool { \__clement_parens:V \l_clement_heads_tl }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \clement_fa_long:n #1
 {% separate the four characters
  \clement_fa_long_aux:NNNN #1
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \clement_fa_long_aux:NNNN #1 #2 #3 #4
 {% add 1-way or 2-way and a space
  #1-way~%
  \bool_if:NTF \l_clement_show_heads_bool
   {% if the boolean is true, add the number of heads
    \tl_if_single:NTF \l_clement_heads_tl
     {
      \__clement_simple:V \l_clement_heads_tl
     }
     {% \D matches anything which is not a digit
      \regex_match:nVTF { \D } \l_clement_heads_tl 
       { \__clement_parens:V \l_clement_heads_tl }
       { \__clement_simple:V \l_clement_heads_tl }
     }
   }
   {% else add S if single-head, M if multi-head
    \str_case:nn { #2 }
     {
      {S}{single}
      {M}{multi}
     }
   }
  -head~% add -head and a space
  \str_case:nn { #3 }
   {% add `non` and a space if nondeterministic
    {N}{non~}
    {D}{}
   }
  deterministic~finite~automaton~% the words
  \str_case:nn { #4 }
   {% add `with` or `without`
    {+}{with~}
    {-}{without~}
   }
  stack% add `stack`
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__clement_parens:n #1 { $( #1 )$ }
\cs_new:Npn \__clement_simple:n #1 { $ #1 $ }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__clement_parens:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__clement_simple:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:nnTF { nV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\fa{2MD+} --- \fa+{2MD+}

\fa{2MD-}[3] --- \fa+{2MD-}[3]

\fa{1MD+}[24] --- \fa+{1MN+}[24]

\fa{2MN+}[k] --- \fa+{2MN+}[k]

\fa*{2MN+}[k+1] --- \fa+{2MN+}[k+1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Woo. This is impressive. However, you might have made some mistake by copying / pasting, since that document cannot get compiled: I get a bunch of ` Undefined control sequence.` And thanks for pointing my English mistake!

Comment: @Clément You need a fully up-to-date TeX system; what distribution are you running?

Comment: An old one `:(` That should probably be the occasion to make an update!

Comment: I manage to compile it by updating to TeXLive 2014. Now I am trying to understand the structure of your file.

Comment: @Clément I added some comments to the code

Comment: You are too fast for me! Thanks a lot for your explanation, I will play a bit with it now, and `texdoc xparse` a lot!

Comment: It would be useful I think to wrap `k+1` in parentheses, probably with some optional arg?  Or let the user add the parentheses and remove them in the short form if present?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I was thinking to this; probably checking with `\regex_match:nVTF` whether `\l_clement_heads_tl` contains just digits or not.

Comment: @egreg: I don't think that `$k$-head` for instance needs parentheses.  I would suggest testing if the arg is surrounded by parentheses.  If it is, then don't add them in the short form nor in the long form.  If it is not, add them to the short form but not the long.  Not sure how to best test for surrounding parentheses, as there are pitfalls: `(a+b)+(c+d)` starts and ends with a parenthesis but is not surrounded by them.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch In my example `$k$-head` doesn't get parentheses: I add them only if the argument doesn't contain digits only *and* is more than one token long.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I should've read your code.  Note that `[^0-9]` can be replaced by `\D`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I keep forgetting those abbreviations.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for those enhancements. I tried to play a bit with `xspace`, but as `\clement_fa_long_aux` is protected, I did not manage to let the "developed version" get hyphenated. It produces large blocks of texts that cannot be spitted across two lines.

Comment: @Clément What should `\xspace` do? There's never use for it when the macro has arguments. The long text *can* be split across lines: it's just text. By the way, I tried the example with `\textwidth=3cm`; it is hyphenated as it should.

Comment: @egreg My bad, I added a `\text` that should not be there. I fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an approach which is initially a little top heavy but allows you to make various formatting choices down the line:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\@xp\expandafter

\newcommand\set{\ae@set}

\def\ae@set(#1){%%
  \@ifnextchar;%%
    {\@ae@set(#1)}%%
    {\ae@@set(#1)}}


\def\@ae@set(#1);{\ae@@set(#1)->#1;}

\def\ae@@set(#1)->#2;{%%
  \def\ae@name{#1}%%
  \ae@parse#2;%%
  }

\def\ae@parse#1#2#3#4;{%%
  \@namedef{automata:\ae@name:way}{#1}%%
  \@namedef{automata:\ae@name:head}{#2}%%
  \@namedef{automata:\ae@name:det}{#3}%%
  \@namedef{automata:\ae@name:stack}{#4}%%
  \ae@parse@automata@name
  \ae@parse@meaning
  \@namedef{automata:\ae@name:name\@xp}\@xp{\ae@automata@name}%%
  \@namedef{automata:\ae@name:meaning\@xp}\@xp{\ae@meaning}%%
  }

\def\ae@test@for@formatting#1#2#3#4{%%
  \def\ae@test{#1}%%
  \@xp\ifx\csname automata:\ae@name:#2\endcsname\ae@test
    \def\ae@formatting{#3}%%
  \else
    \def\ae@formatting{#4}%%
  \fi}

\def\ae@parse@automata@name{%%
  \def\ae@formatting{}%%
  \ae@test@for@formatting{M}{head}{\bfseries\sffamily}{\itshape}%%
  \@xp\def\@xp\ae@automata@name\@xp{%%
    \@xp{\ae@formatting
     \csname automata:\ae@name:way\endcsname
     \csname automata:\ae@name:head\endcsname
     \csname automata:\ae@name:det\endcsname
     \csname automata:\ae@name:stack\endcsname}}}

\def\ae@test@for@meaning#1#2#3#4{%%
  \def\ae@test{#1}%%
  \@xp\ifx\csname automata:\ae@name:#2\endcsname\ae@test
    \edef\ae@meaning{\ae@meaning\space #3}%%
  \else
    \edef\ae@meaning{\ae@meaning\space #4}%%
  \fi}

\def\ae@parse@meaning{%%
  \def\ae@meaning{}%%
  \ae@test@for@meaning{1}{way}{1-way,}{2-way,}%%
  \ae@test@for@meaning{M}{head}{multi-head,}{single-head,}%%
  \ae@test@for@meaning{D}{det}{deterministic}{non-deterministic}%%
  \ae@test@for@meaning{S}{stack}{with stack}{without stack}%%
}

\newcommand\get{\ae@get}

\def\ae@get(#1){%%
  \@ifnextchar;%%
  {\@ae@get(#1)}%%
  {\ae@@get(#1)}}

\def\@ae@get(#1);{\ae@@get(#1)->meaning;}
\def\ae@@get(#1)->#2;{\csname automata:#1:#2\endcsname}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\set(ginger)->1MDS;
\set(rodger)->2SNS;
\set(1MDN);

\begin{tabular}{llll}
  Nickname & Sample getter & Name & Meaning \\\hline
  Ginger & \get(ginger)->way; & \get(ginger)->name; & \get(ginger)->meaning;\\
  Rodger & \get(rodger)->det; & \get(rodger)->name; & \get(rodger)->meaning;\\
  1MDN   & \get(1MDN)->det;   & \get(1MDN)->name;   & \get(1MDN);
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I illustrate above how you can make a decision on how to format things within `\ae@parse@automata@name` by testing whether it's a multiheaded automaton or not.

Of course, `names` don't have to be names like `ginger` or `rodger`, you could just simply say

```
\set(1MDS)->1MDS;
```

and then later call it by

```
\get(1MDS)->name;
```

**UPDATE**

I've rewritten the above code to take into consideration the suggestions made by @egreg.  Also, I've removed the dependency upon `etoolbox`, which is not needed to create this sort of functionality.  Finally, I've improved the *setter* and *getter* to take an *optional* second argument.  That way you can just create the automaton as

```
\set(1MDS);
```

and then call it with

```
\get(1MDS);
```

but I've left the old syntax just in case you really want to anthropomorphize your automata (go Ginger!).

Comment: Wo. This is also very impressive.

Comment: Isn't `\@namedef{...}` better than `\x\def\csname...\endcsname`?

Comment: @egreg Are there analogues to `\@namedef` for `\edef`, `\gdef`, and `\xdef`?

Comment: @egreg Also, I'm not sure how I would do the `\expandafter\endcsname` trick with your suggesetion.

Comment: `\@namedef{abc\expandafter}` works; for `\gdef` you can do `\global\@namedef`; there's nothing in the kernel for `\edef`, but you can do `\providecommand\@nameedef[1]{\expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname}`. A better alias for `\expandafter` is `\@xp` (that's used by `amsmath`).

Comment: @A.Ellett `etoolbox` has `\csdef`, `\csedef`, `\csgdef` and `\csxdef` (and a number of related commands like `\csletcs`...).

Comment: @cgnieder Thank you.  I forgot about those.  Though I was only using `etoolbox` because I was being too lazy (read *sloppy*) to properly handle the expansion.

Comment: It also has a few useful conditionals... if you only have it for `\expandonce`: it's defined `\newcommand\expandonce[1]{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}`

Comment: Your answer is really detailed and clever, but I am less used to this syntax, that I find less handy. I will stick to egreg's solution, but I keep in mind to study yours when I will have the opportunity.

Comment: @clement The fun is in creating an answer.  I wasn't fully keen on what I'd written earlier so edited the code to something more to my liking.  I appreciate that you like though. :)

Answer (score 4):

Since there are other solutions of the “front end” here I just a the solution for *parsing* the argument.

This is just a simple “reader”: it reads a certain element and checks if it's equal to some predefined cases, and, in case it is not, it does what it's inside the `F` argument (`…:nnnF`).

1. First element, `1` or `2`, otherwise does nothing (no error).
2. Second element, `M` or `S`, otherwise puts it in math mode before `-head` (e.g., `k` = `$k$-head`, `{k+1}` = `$k+1$-head`).
3. Third element, `D` or `N`, otherwise does nothing.
4. Fourth element, `+` or nothing (or something else, it doesn't matter). I'm not sure if you ever want an explicit “without stack” so I leave it to you.

The second element, if more than one token, must be enclosed in braces, e.g., `\automata{1{(k+1)}N+}`.

**UPDATE:** I forgot some part of the “sentence”.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \automata { m }
  {
    \clement_automata_process:n {#1}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \clement_check_item:nnnF #1 #2
  {
    \str_case_e:nnF { \tl_item:nn {#1} {#2} }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \clement_check_item:nnn #1 #2
  {
    \str_case_e:nn { \tl_item:nn {#1} {#2} }
  }
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \clement_automata_process:n #1
  {
    \clement_check_item:nnn {#1} { 1 }
      {
        { 1 } { $1$-way }
        { 2 } { $2$-way }
      } ~
    \clement_check_item:nnnF {#1} { 2 }
      {
        { S } { single-head }
        { M } { multiple-head }
      }
      { $\tl_item:nn {#1} { 2 }$-head } ~
    \clement_check_item:nnn {#1} { 3 }
      {
        { D } { deterministic }
        { N } { non-deterministic }
      } ~ finite ~ automaton ~ 
    \clement_check_item:nnn {#1} { 4 }
      {
        { + } { with ~ stack }
%       { - } { without ~ stack} % if it's needed you can uncomment it
      } % Or you can add it here if you want it (nnnF) always “without” unless `+` is given
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\obeylines
\automata{1MD+}
\automata{2kN}
\automata{2{(k+1)}N+}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beware that I don't know anything about expansion. Reading egreg's answer I see that he uses `\str_case:nn` when I use (at some point) `\str_case_x:nn`; he also uses `\cs_new_protected:Npn` while I didn't protect mine… This may be “wrong” in other cases (while works well in the lines I wrote :P).

Comment: I must admit it is hard for me to understand precisely the benefit of your modification.

Comment: The `+` instead of `+S` is because it's much more easier to check one token than two (at least in my approach). Now, the only modification is (unless I failed to understand, or made an error) the “second token”. Is that what you don't understand? If you ask a more precise question I will try to answer it. However, I think it's relatively easy to understand how the code works.

Comment: @Clément I was adding a more detailed answer, but internet went off and I lose it :( I thought TeX.SX saved some sort of drafts… but I can't recover the text. If you have any doubt about anything don't hesitate to ask ;)

Comment: Sorry for the waste of time. I do not think it is necessary to write the explanation again, at least not just for me. Thanks anyway!