# Define a new command with parameters inside newcommand

Tags: macros, nesting, parameters

I have read the question and answers about:

- [Defining a newcommand, with variable name, inside another newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28704/defining-a-newcommand-with-variable-name-inside-another-newcommand)
- [How to define a macro to create a new macro with a name passed as its argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25452/how-to-define-a-macro-to-create-a-new-macro-with-a-name-passed-as-its-argument)
- [What exactly do \csname and \endcsname do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39380/what-exactly-do-csname-and-endcsname-do)

What I want to do is similar, but one step further.
I would like to define a new command with a variable name, but the new command should have parameters (exactly one in my case).

I tried to use the hash symbol `#` twice, like this:

```
\newcommand{\deffun}[1]{\expandafter\newcommand[1]\csname #1\endcsname[1]{#1(##1)}}
```

But this does not seem to work and I am too confused or ignorant to produce a mwe with nesting of macro definitions with parameters.
For an answer, pointing me to the relevant place of the documentation would be enough.
It looks like nesting of macro definitions is not a commonly used nor explained feature.

PD: I was almost right, it is like this:

```
\newcommand{\deffun}[1]{\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname[1]{#1(##1)}}
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39380/what-exactly-do-csname-and-endcsname-do and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109615/best-practice-for-creating-user-defined-command-names

Comment: What is this `\newcommand[1]` supposed to do?

Comment: See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188478/8528 (shameless self-promotion; but examples are similar).

Comment: Use `\def\deffun#1{\expadafter\def\csname#1\endcsname##1{#1(##1)}}`. The combination of TeX primitives `\csname`, `\endcsname` with the LaTeX macro `\newcommand` looks funny. And pointer to the documentation? The TeXbook.

Comment: @jon `*facepalm*` I'm sorry, I was getting errors and I thought that everything was wrong because (honestly) I had no idea of what I was doing. Turns out that was the only problem to make it work...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\deffunA#1{\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname##1{#1(##1)}}

\newcommand{\deffunB}[1]{\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname[1]{#1(##1)}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\deffunC}[1]{\csdef{#1}##1{#1(##1)}}

\begin{document}

\deffunA{abc}
$\abc{123}$

\deffunB{ghi}
$\ghi{123}$

\deffunC{jkl}
$\jkl{123}$

\end{document}
```

`\deffunA` uses a pure TeX way of defining a macro, while `\deffunB` is a LaTeX-related way of doing it. `\deffunC` uses [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) which provides a neat interface for defining macros. See section **3.1.1 Macro Definitions** of the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf). In fact, `\csdef` uses the LaTeX-defined `\@namedef`... yet another way of achieving what you're after.

Comment: Comprehensive, exhaustive and precise. Very good answer.

Comment: +1: Do you recommend one of the options over the others?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Whichever makes sense to you. The hope would be that people understand the concept so they can expand/change it as needed.

Answer (score 3):

The error is in the wrong `\newcommand[1]`.

Here's a way using `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\deffun}{m}
 {
  \exp_args:Nc \newcommand{#1}[1]{#1(##1)}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\deffun{foo}

\texttt{\meaning\foo}

\end{document}
```

The output is

> `\long macro:#1->foo(#1)`

The trick is that `\exp_args:Nc` jumps over the next token (`N`), takes the next braced group as an argument and makes a control sequence name out of it (`c`), and restarts from the jumped over token.

A possible “more proper” way, taking into account that the macro to be defined has just one parameter, would be

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\deffun}{m}
 {
  \cs_new:cpn {#1} ##1 { #1 ( ##1 ) }
 }
```

that essentially uses the same idea; note that `\cs_new:...` refuses to define an already existing command, but the definition is global (contrary to `\newcommand`).

Several variations are possible.

Comment: `\cs_new:cpn {#1} { #1 ( ##1 ) }` should be `\cs_new:cpn {#1} ##1 { #1 ( ##1 ) }`