# Help defining a newcommand for short cut to equation

Tags: macros, equations

Is there anyway to define a newcommand for an environment shortcut ? This is what I have so far, but is not working as I would like to.

```
\newcommand{\beq}{\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:}
```

and

```
\newcommand{\eeq}{\end{equation}}
```

I would like to define a command such that typing

```
\eq{1} 
x + y = z 
\eeq
```

is the same as typing something similar to

```
 \begin{equation} 
\label{eq:1} 
x + y = z
\end{equation}.
```

Would this be possible ? I have read the posts in [Define a new command with parameters inside newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266811/define-a-new-command-with-parameters-inside-newcommand) and [What exactly do \csname and \endcsname do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39380/what-exactly-do-csname-and-endcsname-do) but did not fully understand so it would be great if someone could help me out as I am relatively new to latex.
The compiler I am using is texstudios and would greatly appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: No No No No No, you don't do that! Get a decent editor that lets you be lazy, but don't use LaTeX macros to shorten math.

Comment: as previously noted, best not to use numeric labels. In general you can do that but you can not do that with AMS math environments, as documented. Even where it works it is usually a bad idea as environments are the major syntactic construct introduced by latex and it is much easier for your editor to help navigate and display the code properly if you do not hide the structure,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand your point but I write all my equations inside environments using theorems so I could still keep track of the structure. I will also make sure to skip a line for each shortcut so that I still can display the code properly. Thank you for the advice though !

Comment: No! _never_ put a blank line before a display math environment that produces entirely the wrong spacing if you do.

Comment: I strongly advice against the proposed solutions, as they are not solutions. Math environments should *never* be hidden. Please don't do that.  You probably will get into problems later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or even shorter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\eq}[2]{\begin{equation} \label{eq:#1} #2 \end{equation}}

\begin{document}

    \eq{1}{x + y = z}

    \eq{2}{a + b = c}

\end{document}
```

After you type in your doc, you can "translate" back your source tex file to regular environments with `sed` or alike. I do this very often despite what others have said (which I normally agree - but not when you have 10000 equations nested as heck in all sorts of environments in a book with 3 nested translations in the same file). TeX brags about letting you concentrate on the contents doesn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Use the below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\beq}[1]{\begin{equation}\label{eq:#1}}
\newcommand{\eeq}{\end{equation}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\beq{1} 
x + y = z 
\eeq

\beq{2} 
x + y = z 
\eeq

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: No, no and no. The fact that the question asks for something ridiculous, conceptually wrong and actually useless does not mean we have to answer it. Moreover, placing two equations in a row is bad for their spacing; and have you tried doing the same thing with `align` or `gather` rather than with `equation`?