# Functions and new commands in latex

Tags: macros, watermark

I'm having some problem creating a new function.

I found in another topic a method to create a watermark on pages, and to make my work easier, I created a function when called, inserts the watermark on my sheets. So far I have this code.

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{transparent}


\newcommand{\watermark}[1]{
    \AddToShipoutPicture{
    
        \put(0,0){
        
            \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{
                \vfill
                \centering
            
                {\transparent{0.15}\fontsize{150pt}{1.5pt}\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont \begin{turn}{45} \textbf{#1}\end{turn}}
                \vfill}}}
        
    }
```

However, I want to optimize this command even more, passing through the mandatory command the text to be displayed, and optional parameters the following data: "rotation, transparency and font size". But I don't know how to create a command with all these optional and mandatory parameters.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not using a specialized package such as `draftwatermark`?

Comment: (a) Different ways of defining a macro with parameters: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266811/define-a-new-command-with-parameters-inside-newcommand (b) A `key=value` method is more powerful and flexible; the `\newcommand` method can have 9 parameters, only the first parameter can be optional (although nesting of `\newcommand`s is possible) (c) In expl3, multiple optional parameters are allowed, but are positional, not named (although named parameters can be coded up in and out of expl3 (there was a TeX.se question about naming parameters so they could be typed in any order)).

Comment: @egreg I created a new command with draftwatermark package too, but I have this same need. I tried with xwatermark package too, but this one didn't work.

Comment: @Cicada Its exactly what I need. I found this post, wich explain how to create key=value method. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34312/how-to-create-a-command-with-key-values.

Comment: I suggest using [CTAN eso-pic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic).

Answer (score 1):

Reading the answer of @Cicada and the link for me sent, I found what I really need. In this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34312/how-to-create-a-command-with-key-values) I found a method to create the command with all the parameters. I got this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{transparent}

\makeatletter
\define@key{watermark}{fontsize}{\def\wm@fontsize{#1}}
\define@key{watermark}{transparency}{\def\wm@transparency{#1}}
\define@key{watermark}{align}{\def\wm@align{#1}}

\setkeys{watermark}{fontsize=100pt,transparency=0.15,align=45}%
\newcommand{\watermark}[2][]{
    \setkeys{watermark}{#1}
    \AddToShipoutPicture{
        \put(0,0){  
            \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{
                \vfill
                \centering      
                {\transparent{\wm@transparency}\fontsize{\wm@fontsize}{1.5pt}\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont \begin{turn}{\wm@align} \textbf{#2}\end{turn}}
                \vfill}}}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \watermark{DRAFT}
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much for the attention.